# Magento 1.9.2 : Hide specific categories form new arrival section

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to hide some specific categories form new arrival section on the homepage. I am using following code but not able to achieve.

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')->setPageSize(6);
```

Comment: Hello @VishvajitKumar, welcome! Based on your question I'm not exactly sure what you want achieve. From ALL products you want to cut out (filter out) those, that are assigned to a specific category?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Collection for your requirement.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4));
$_productCollection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('ccp' => 'catalog_category_product'),"ccp.product_id = e.entity_id",array('category_ids'=>'GROUP_CONCAT(ccp.category_id)'));
$_productCollection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')->setPageSize(6);
$_productCollection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
$_productCollection->getSelect()->having('category_ids NOT LIKE "%10%" AND category_ids NOT LIKE "%51%"');
```

In having clause, You use your category ids what you want to hide instead of 10 and 51.
**category_ids NOT LIKE "%10%" AND category_ids NOT LIKE "%51%"**

If Your products mapped with only one category,you can use follwoing collection

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4));
$_productCollection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('ccp' => 'catalog_category_product'),"ccp.product_id = e.entity_id AND ccp.category_id NOT IN (10,51)");
$_productCollection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')->setPageSize(6);
$_productCollection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: Welcome bro. Please "accept" the answer as well so that it will be marked as solved and will help others with same issue. Good day.